# What happens to original changesets after an Hg "history rewrite" (histedit, commit --amend), and how can they be recovered?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, recovery, changeset

In Git - with it's immutable changeset objects and mutable refs - I know that the original commits remain, which gives me a warm fuzzy feeling after an 'oops' "history rewriting" moment.

For example, after a "history rewriting" `git rebase` the original changesets (cbe7698, 09c6268) are still there and a new changeset (08832c0) was added. I can easily restore/access the other changesets until such a time as they are pruned.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)
* 08832c0 (HEAD -> master) Added bar and quxx to foo.txt
| * cbe7698 Added quxx to foo.txt
| * 09c6268 Added bar to foo.txt
|/
* 895c9bb Added foo.txt
```

Likewise, even a `git commit --amend` preserves the original/amended commit (d58dabc) and adds a new changeset:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)
* d9bb795 (HEAD -> master) Added cats and dogs to pets.txt
| * d58dabc Added cats to pets.txt
|/
* 08832c0 Added pets.txt
```

However, **what happens in Hg after a "history rewriting" operation?**

Do the original commits cease to exist? And if they still do exist, how can they be accessed and/or recovered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you have the evolve extension installed or not. If you have the evolve extension installed, the only command that will actually remove revisions from the repository is `hg strip`; other commands leave the original commits in place, but hide them. You can see them with `hg log --hidden` (or other commands with the `--hidden` flag). If you want to get rid of them permanently, `hg strip --hidden -r 'extinct()'` can be used [1].

Most people, however, will just be using base Mercurial. In this case (and for `hg strip` even with evolve), the removed changesets will be stored as bundles in `.hg/strip-backup`. A Mercurial bundle is basically a read-only overlay repository; you can use `hg log -R`, `hg tip -R`, `hg incoming`, `hg pull`, etc. on it. This is all you need in principle, but it can be a bit cumbersome typing out the paths.

For convenience, Facebook has published a [number of experimental extensions](https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental) for Mercurial. Among them, the backups extension provides a convenience command (`hg backups`) that basically lists the commits in each bundle in `.hg/strip-backup` (similar to what `hg incoming` with an appropriate template would do) and `hg backups --recover` to pull in the changesets from the stripped commits (similar to what `hg pull` would do).

[1] Note that even then, a backup will be stored in `.hg/strip-backup`. If you want to get rid of them *really* permanently, you will also have to remove that backup.