# Prevent 'hg push' (without branch name or revision) from pushing all changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, push

I find that (unlike some other implementations), Mercurial is over zealous on what it pushes - and a pushed commit is a non-editable commit.

I have trained myself to use `hg push -b branchawesome` or `hg push -r awesomer`. However, sometimes my fingers do an "oops" and everything - including transient Draft work - is pushed to the upstream repository.

Is there a Mercurial-way to either prevent `hg push` outright or require a "force" flag, as in `hg push --draft`?

---

I'd prefer not to use [Secret Phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases). Despite how I've worded the question, the goal is to help/encourage others to be specific about what changes are pushed - *without* incurring an entirely new concept.

Comment: 1. With Evolve Extension all changes are mutable 2. "Polished history" is a habit of cheating Git-boys (OK, *I*'ll not afraid of my *dirty WIP*, even if I'll share it by mistake), why you want to be also "trendy"? 3. You can (?) create hook on push-target for blocking plain push

Comment: However the *secret phase* is designed to provide a (or the) solution to your issue (among some other issues). What is wrong in making use of it? If you want to push, then explicitly make draft the changeset you want to push. It's also no concept which really interferes with anything else

Comment: @LazyBadger 1) The DAG (which altering changesets alters) is only usefully mutable until pushed. There is *no* extension that can change this. 2) Please leave out such nonsense speculation about being a 'cheating Git-[fan]boy'. I have been using Mq long before using Git (and long before rebase, histedit, and the Evolve Extensions existed for Hg). If you like submitting every single trivial mistake or not organizing changesets into nice bundles, then that's your preference just as much as it is mine to tidy up first. 3) How would such a hook be created?

Comment: @planetmaker I am sensing that best solution is to organize some Hg training sessions :}

Comment: @LazyBadger Seriously, Hg and Git are fundamentally the same (except for some awkward details) - and wishing to clean up the local DAG in either is possible and entirely independent of the tool used.  If committing often the changesets will be over-chatty and quite likely contain trivial mistakes (even including something as minor as non-prefered syntax formatting) fixed in close following subsequent commits and lead to fragmentation of even small tasks / work units. If anything, 'cheating Git-[fan]boys' should be thanked for the git-like history editing in Hg. (Mq works on stacks.)

Comment: @user2864740 the concept of phases may be new, if you come from any other VCS. However their name is (IMHO) quite self-explanatory and the impact on workflow is minimal, if you choose secret as default phase for your commits.  While I consider Reimer Behrend's solution an interesting one (+1 to that), it is also just a workaround which solves something which is already  solved in core mercurial much more elegantly, more future-proof, more fail-proof and in a *much* more versatile way (if you make use of both, a non-publishing repo to exchange draft changesets, and the evolve extension)

Comment: @planetmaker I'm not against the concept of phases, but was rather looking if there was a 'quick win' to encourage a shift in Hg usage. I work with many very smart people .. who use Hg enough to pull+merge+killallheads and use an amalgamated commit/push cycle. Having an Hg instructional (on the use of phases and other Hg 'secrets') would probably be the right approach. The repos here are already quite the 'complex magic' (outside of my immediate influence) so mainly it's about helping others manage individual flows better and mitigate some not-too-uncommon issues.

Comment: @LazyBadger I'm glad I "made" your day, but I would rather have my statements sparked an inquiry (on your behalf) on how Hg and Git actually work. In both cases the repositories are represented by a DAG of changesets. Each commit is a new changeset; be it from a `histedit` or `rebase` or `--amend` (with or without the "Evolution" extension) or `qfinish`. Git [makes this readily transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833510) when doing 'history editing changes' (in the log and how it handles it's first-class branch concept) but the fundamental operation is the same.

Comment: http://evolution.experimentalworks.net/doc/user-guide.html#life-with-evolve-advanced-usage http://evolution.experimentalworks.net/doc/sharing.html#sharing-with-multiple-developers-code-review

Comment: @LazyBadger Thanks for the links. It looks to be a useful Hg tool (I have the extension installed for the sake of the safety net it adds to rebase/histedit) - normally I would drop back to Mq (with the appropriate rebase or two) for such changes, but Mq is problematic in that it works on a stack, not a DAG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a note: Mercurial will not by default let you push a new head/branch without explicitly saying so (you'll get an error message telling you that you need `--new-branch` or `-f` to actually push your changes). Accidentally pushing more than you intended can only happen if you have commits on multiple existing branches.

Second, the easy (but problematic) solution is to use an alias for push, e.g. `push = push -r .` will be more restrictive. However, this overrides the push command, making it difficult to get at the original version (which you can do via `rawpush = !$HG --config alias.push=push "$@"`, for example).

The cleanest way is to use an extension that wraps the push command and provides a different default. e.g.:

```
from mercurial import extensions, commands

testedwith = "3.5"

default_push_rev = "."

# alternative choices

# Push the current revision, but only if it is a head
# default_push_rev = ". and head()"

# Push the current revisions and all revisions depending on it
# default_push_rev = "descendants(.)"

# Push the most recent head that follows the current revision
# default_push_rev = "last(descendants(.))"

# Push the tip revision (i.e. the chronologically most recent commit).
# default_push_rev = "tip"

# Push only public change sets
# default_push_rev = "public()"

def override_push(original_cmd, ui, repo, *pats, **opts):
  have_rev = False
  for opt in ["rev", "branch"]:
    if opts.has_key(opt) and opts[opt]:
      have_rev = True
  if not have_rev:
    opts["rev"] = [default_push_rev]
  return original_cmd(ui, repo, *pats, **opts)

def uisetup(ui):
  extensions.wrapcommand(commands.table, "push", override_push)
```

Unlike the alias, this will only change the default revisons to be pushed if none is explicitly provided. Note that there are multiple choices that may make sense. The above code is setup to push `.` by default, but there are alternatives that you may like better.

Note also that the extension does not override the `hg outgoing` command, but if you wish, that can be easily done by duplicating the `wrapcommand` line and substituting `"outgoing"` for `"push"` in the duplicate line.

To get the original behavior, just use `hg push -r 'all()'`, possibly as an alias:

```
[alias]
push-all = push -r 'all()'
```

EDIT: Fixed a bug in the original code which ignored the branch option.

Comment: Excellent! Can you, please, add also solution with (prechangegroup?) *hook on push-target*, which will block **only pushes without parameters** (only pushes - because prechangegroup will file on other events also, without parameters - because it's requested)

Comment: @LazyBadger I don't think this is possible (except for pushing to local repositories), because the wire protocol does not transfer that information. You can trigger an error in the extension (`from mercurial import util; raise util.Abort("no revision provided for push")`) instead of setting the revision to a default value, of course.

Comment: No, I'll be happy with your extension (as natural Mercurial-way). Can you collect all these pieces of useful tricks in one common place (I can recall also good example with custom keyword over tiny extension)? If I may be permitted to ask for such favor

Comment: @LazyBadger I've been thinking about putting up some of this small stuff on Bitbucket, but have been a bit reluctant, because once you start hosting code publicly, there's also an expectation that you'll maintain it (whereas on SO, the code can more easily just be edited by others). Plus, some of the code needs to be polished more to work without the context of an SO post (for example, the help text for `hg push` would have to be corrected). I'll think it over, though.

Comment: The problem *is* there are multiple commits on different branches.. after the feedback here it seems that this might be a problem better solved at the 'soft' level, although this is an interesting solution (and shows how easy it is to customize hg).